# Проблема отображения списка страниц и блоков в Magento 2

Tags: magento

Осваиваю Magento 2. В ходе некоторых манипуляций с кешем и объединением файлов стилей в настройках вид отображения списка таблиц и блоков внутри ПУ изменился. Должен выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А отображаеся так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, часть стилей просто улетучилась, без каких-либо правок кода. Можно ли это дело в настройках или через SSH обновить?

Comment: Консоль браузера какие-нибудь ошибки выдает? Если да, то какие? Первое что приходит в голову - обновить кеш, но думаю вы это уже попробовали.

Answer (score 1):

Порядок действий таких случаях следующий:

- проверить какой файл css не подгрузился
- проверить есть ли он на сервере в папке pub/static
- если нет, проверить есть ли он в app/design/VendorName/ThemeName... либо в app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/... либо /vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/...
- если есть удалить pub/static и сделать из консоли в руте `мадженты php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` и `php bin/magento cache:flush`
- если нет проверить чистую мадженту и добавить отсутствующий файл
- если все есть, но не работает - убрать в систем конфиге мердж css и почистить кэш
- проверить наличие варниша и прочего лиха и убедиться, что кэш там тоже почищен

Если не помогло пишите, есть еще варианты, но 99,9% лечится именно так.